# Function Key F3 not working in Windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have to select a row when i click on F1, F2 and F3.
In Windows Mobile F1 and F2 seems to be working fine in Form_KeyDown.

But on click of F3 the mobile Dial up opens.

How do i change the default F3 functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API function [AllKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599629.aspx) to receive key press notifications for all key presses (including ones reserved by the system) in your application.  You just need to write some code to detect when F3 is pressed and react.  There is an old MSDN blog post showing how to P/Invoke this method from C# [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikefrancis/archive/2009/03/28/porting-gapi-keys-to-wm-6-1-and-6-5.aspx).